# how to remove edges from largest connected component?

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx

i am working on dynamic graph, i want to remove edges from the largest connected component,here is the example of code i wrote

```
    graph=dn.read_snapshots('mytxt', nodetype=int, timestamptype=int)

 print(nx.number_connected_components(graph))
S=[len(c) for c in sorted(nx.connected_components(graph), key=len, reverse=True)]
print(S)----[150, 1]
```

here i have two components, and i need to work with the largest one, the one with 150

```
y=[]
 rand_set = set(random.sample(range(20), 5))
for (u,v,t) in **largest**.interactions():
        #m,n = pair(u, v)
        if r in rand_set:
            s.remove_edge((u,v,t))
            if(nx.is_connected(s)==True):
                y.append(u,v,t)
            else:
                graph.add_interaction((u,v,t))
            r+=1
```

here `largest` means need to work on largest connected component of this graph
in this code, I randomly remove edge from the connected component and append to y,however this code is not giving me any result. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Let's use an example graph to more easily see how this could be done:

```
l = [('maths', 'physics'), ('astronomy', 'physics'), ('history', 'archaeology'), ('environmental science', 'physics'), ('maths', 'astronomy'), ('history', 'literature'), ('astronomy', 'astrophysics'), ('literature', 'philosophy'), ('biology', 'physics')]
graph = nx.from_edgelist(l)
```

So we've built a graph which looks as follows:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(graph, scale=20, k=3/np.sqrt(graph.order()))
nx.draw(graph, pos=pos,
        node_color='lightblue', 
        with_labels=True, 
        node_size=500)
```

[image]

So the graph has 2 connected components, the  largest one of which is the one that appears at the left of the figure.
To find the largest component subgraph, you could use `connected_component_subgraphs`, and find the maximum, using `len` as a `key` function.

```
S = max(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(graph), key=len)
```

Then get a random choice of the existing edges in this subgraph using `random.choices`, setting `k` to the value of interest:

```
edges_to_remove = random.choices(list(S.edges()), k=2)
# [('physics', 'biology'), ('physics', 'environmental science')]
```

In this case for instance we'll be removing the edges connecting the nodes `('physics', 'biology')` and `('physics', 'environmental science')`

And then similarly to what you where doing, we can iterate over the random choice of edges `edges_to_remove` and remove them from the graph using `remove_edge`:

```
for edge in edges_to_remove:  
    graph.remove_edge(*edge)
```

Resulting in the following graph:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @yatu, but this method S = max(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(graph), key=len) is not implimented for dynamic graph, this is the error NetworkXNotImplemented: Method not implemented for dynamic graphs, is there a way to do it for dynamic graph?

Comment: mm try chenging `S` from my approach to `S = max(nx.strongly_connected_components(graph), key=len)` @christinamuro

Comment: Than you@yatu, but this one works for directed graphs

Comment: Hmm not sure how the connected components can be found for dynamic graphs really :/ Hope this was helpful anyways @christinamuro If I find out I'll update

Comment: What do you get with `type(graph)` @christina ?

Comment: subgraph= max(nx.connected_components(s), key=len) , result is a set @yatu, Thank you